# Choosing dynamic range in VBA - How to adjust the code for a range that changes location in the sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, range

VBA newbie here. Sorry for the silly question, but I just can't find the answer I'm looking for. Let's say I have several ranges:

```
A9:A27
A31:A44
A49:A68
```

with spaces between the ranges.
I have to paste these onto a new worksheet, one after the other without any spaces, so that this worksheet could be later used as Pivot source. The catch is that with time I will need to add new rows of data to these ranges in the future, meaning that the row numbers will change, e.g. like this:

```
A9:A29
A33:A48
A53:A72
```

The top range is easy, as the top row will remain unchanged, but how do I go about other ranges? Currently the code for the second range looks like this:

```
copysheet.Range("A9").End(xlDown).Offset(4,0).Select
copysheet.Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Copy
pastesheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

My problem is that I will have to paste data from a different workbook, therefore I want to avoid activating workbooks and using `ActiveCell` and such. I'm sure there is an easier, cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If I was lazy (which I am), I would not bother with putting the `.End(xlDown)` in a `Do While` loop to find all chunks manually, and would instead do

```vb
Dim r As Range ' Declare a variable to hold the result

' Limiting ourselves only to the used portion of the column A...
With Application.Intersect(copysheet.Range("A:A"), copysheet.UsedRange)
  On Error Resume Next 'Ignore errors because unfortunately SpecialCells throws errors when it does not find anything
  Set r = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) ' Find all cells with regular non-formula values
  If r Is Nothing Then ' If there are no such cells
    Set r = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas) ' Find all cells with formulas instead
  Else ' Otherwise, if there were cells with regular values
    Set r = Application.Union(r, .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)) ' Also find cells with formulas and make it a single range with the previously found non-formula range
  End If
  On Error GoTo 0 ' Stop ignoring errors because we're done with SpecialCells
End With

If Not r Is Nothing Then ' If we found at least someting
  r.Copy ' Copy it
  pastesheet.Cells(pastesheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues ' and paste to destination
  Application.CutCopyMode = False ' then remove than annoying selection marquee
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for this, could you please be so kind to add comments to the code, explaining the actions? This is really new to me and I'm lost :( with comments I'd be able to understand better what this does. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

This starts with three fixed starting point in column **A**, determines the dimensions of the three associated blocks and copies the blocks to `Sheet2`:

```
Sub copyBLOCKS()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range
    Dim r1x As Range, r2x As Range, r3x As Range
    Dim N As Long

    Set r1 = Range("A9")
    Set r2 = Range("A31")
    Set r3 = Range("A49")
    N = 1

    Range(r1, r1.End(xlDown)).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & N)
    N = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Range(r2, r2.End(xlDown)).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & N)
    N = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Range(r3, r3.End(xlDown)).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & N)

End Sub
```